# Iptables configuration for NAT with KVM

Tags: iptables

I have a server with a public ip (`142.0.0.142`). This server hosts a KVM virtual machine (`192.168.100.10`) and redirects the HTTP/S traffic to this VM.
I followed [those instructions](https://jamielinux.com/docs/libvirt-networking-handbook/custom-nat-based-network.html) to configure a "Custom NAT-based network".
When I use the public ip `142.0.0.142` to perform an HTTP request, it works perfectly and the traffic is redirected to the VM. However, when I use the public ip to perform an HTTP request from the host or the guest, the connection fails.

Here is the content of `/etc/iptables/rules.v4`:

```
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
# DHCP packets sent to VMs have no checksum (due to a longstanding bug).
-A POSTROUTING -o virbr10 -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j CHECKSUM --checksum-fill
COMMIT

*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]

# Modify the destination address of packets received on ports 80 and 443.
-A PREROUTING -d 142.0.0.142/32 -p tcp -m tcp --syn -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.100.10

# Do not masquerade to these reserved address blocks.
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.100.0/24 -d 224.0.0.0/24 -j RETURN
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.100.0/24 -d 255.255.255.255/32 -j RETURN

# Masquerade all packets going from VMs to the LAN/Internet.
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.100.0/24 ! -d 192.168.100.0/24 -p tcp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.100.0/24 ! -d 192.168.100.0/24 -p udp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.100.0/24 ! -d 192.168.100.0/24 -j MASQUERADE

COMMIT

*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]

# Allow basic INPUT traffic.
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 8 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT

# Accept SSH connections.
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --syn -m conntrack --ctstate NEW --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

# Accept DNS (port 53) and DHCP (port 67) packets from VMs.
-A INPUT -i virbr10 -p udp -m udp -m multiport --dports 53,67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i virbr10 -p tcp -m tcp -m multiport --dports 53,67 -j ACCEPT

# Reject everything else.
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

# Allow established traffic to the private subnet.
-A FORWARD -d 192.168.100.0/24 -o virbr10 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# Allow outbound traffic from the private subnet.
-A FORWARD -s 192.168.100.0/24 -i virbr10 -j ACCEPT

# Allow traffic between virtual machines.
-A FORWARD -i virbr10 -o virbr10 -j ACCEPT

# Allow packets that have been forwarded to particular ports on the VM.
-A FORWARD -d 192.168.100.10/32 -o virbr10 -p tcp -m tcp --syn -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j ACCEPT

# Reject everything else.
-A FORWARD -i virbr10 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -o virbr10 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

COMMIT
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For The VM failure, it's because [NAT hairpinning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#NAT_loopback) must be used to avoid a system in the server's LAN getting direct non-NAT-ed reply traffic (including the server seeing its own source address as incoming traffic): it would fail.

So for VMs in the system's LAN, including the server itself, do NAT harpinning. Change the source IP address whenever it's from the same LAN as the intended destination's LAN and DNAT already happened, as memorized in conntrack's state and retrievable using [`-m conntrack --ctstate DNAT`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-extensions.8#conntrack)   (`-d 192.168.100.0/24` is both not needed and insufficient so isn't added):

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -m conntrack -s 192.168.100.0/24 --ctstate DNAT -j SNAT --to-source 142.0.0.142
```

Actually, any source IP address that would go through or to the host is fine: 142.0.0.142, 192.168.100.1 or even any fictive address such as 192.0.2.1 as long as it's reachable with the VM's default route. It's even possible to map the source address in the LAN to another source address in another (possibly fictive) LAN such as 192.168.101.0/24 ([`NETMAP`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-extensions.8#NETMAP) in nat/POSTROUTING alters the source):

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -m conntrack -s 192.168.100.0/24 --ctstate DNAT -j NETMAP --to 192.168.101.0/24
```

It's thus possible to distinguish in the application's logs running on the VM at 192.168.100.10 a client from 192.168.100.0/24 calling directly (no address change anywhere), the same calling the public address (source becoming 192.168.101.x), and the host as client calling directly 192.168.100.10 (no address change anywhere).

---

For the host itself calling the public address, there's no routing involved, so nat/PREROUTING doesn't happen for initial traffic and no redirection happens at all. Instead, nat/OUTPUT does happen. The nat/PREROUTING rule has to be copied to nat/OUTPUT sometimes with a slight change (here no change appears needed):

```
  iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d 142.0.0.142/32 -p tcp -m tcp --syn -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.100.10
```